# Inserting a special character in a input

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple question. I need to insert this two character ( in a val of an input but it escape me \ and visualiza only (. I suppose \ is a special character but i need it like it is.

Example

```
      $('input#area').val("Try type \( \int_{-N}^{N} e^x \, dx \) .");
```

must visualizza all the \ in the input.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want a literal `\` you need to write `\\`.